# Solve laravel validation for field with relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have some problem where the validation is failing for my blade template with dropdown select on related table. I tried to searched for an answer but cannot found it.

To temporarily comment out the the field 'business_unit_id' inside the array in validate function to avoid the error.

In controller update function:

```
    $item = CostCenter::findOrFail($id);
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'code' => 'bail|min:4|required|max:6',
        'descr' => 'bail|min:4|required|max:50',
        'business_unit_id' => 'required|integer',
    ]);

    $item->fill($validatedData);
    $item->business_unit_id = $request->businessUnit;

    $item->save();
    $request->session()->flash('status', 'Cost centers record was updated!');

    return redirect()->route('costCenters.show', ['cost_centers' => $item->id]);
```

In blade template:

```
        <label for="businessUnit" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Business Unit</label>
            <select name="businessUnit" class="form-control">
                @foreach (App\Models\BusinessUnit::all() as $data)
                    <option value="{{ $data->id }}"
                        {{ old('business_unit_id', $cost_centers->business_unit_id ?? '1')
                            != $data->id ?: 'selected' }}>
                        {{ $data->code }} - {{ $data->descr }}
                    </option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
```

The notification received is "The business unit id field is required." with my error helper.

Comment: You have named the select element as `"businessUnit"`.  It should be named as `"business_unit_id"`.

Comment: I tried before to name the control same as the model field requiring validation, but the validation does not function. It render an error of SQLSTATE[23000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'business_unit_id', table 'epms.dbo.cost_centers'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails. (SQL: update [cost_centers] set [business_unit_id] = ?, [cost_centers].[updated_at] = 2019-08-14 09:25:11.360 where [id] = 1)

Comment: Hi Suraj, just to let you know that now your suggestion works. I do not understand why it is not when I tried those previously.

Comment: I realized now that the reason it is not probably work previously is that I committed the changes in "create" instead of "update" in controller. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'code' => 'bail|min:4|required|max:6',
    'descr' => 'bail|min:4|required|max:50',
    'businessUnit' => 'required|integer',
]);
```

Use businessUnit instead of business_unit_id 
as we have to use the name of select tag...
don't use the id of options tag..

Comment: I also tried that before and it failed, tried it again now and it is the same. SQLSTATE[42S22]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'businessUnit'. (SQL: update [cost_centers] set [businessUnit] = 89, [cost_centers].[updated_at] = 2019-08-14 09:47:01.178 where [id] = 1). I think the comment above is more appropriate as the select name is the same as the field being validated. I just don't know why it is not passed with validation even it is confirmed that the request field being passed to the controller has value.

Comment: before validating data just check what all data is being return from blade....by using dd($request->all());

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code...and use use keyword to of the code like **use Validator;**

```
    $rules = [
           'code' => 'bail|min:4|required|max:6',
           'descr' => 'bail|min:4|required|max:50',
           'businessUnit' => 'required|integer|exists:business_unit,id',
    ];

    $message = [
        'code.required' => 'code is required.',
        'descr.required' => 'description field is required.',
        'businessUnit.required' => 'The business unit id field is required.',

    ];

     $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules,$message);
      if ($validator->fails()) {
      $arr = array("status"=>400,"msg"=>$validator->errors()- 
     >first(),"result"=>array());
      }
       else
       {
      your code write in this section
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For any request data validation in controller You can try like this:

```
$rule=array(
        'code' => 'bail|min:4|required|max:6',
        'descr' => 'bail|min:4|required|max:50',
        'business_unit_id' => 'required|integer',
);
$validator= Validator::make($request->all(),$rule);
```